# How can I declare a new operator "!??" (test object is not null)

Tags: c#, generics, nullable, unary-operator

**Is there a way to declare a unary operator such as '!??'**

I imagine something like this (non working code)

```
public bool operator !??<T> (this <T> item) {
    return item != null;
}
```

so I would use it like such

```
// day is a value and might possibly be null
string greeting = name !?? "hello there " + name;
```

I find myself often having to do this awkwardness

```
// day is a value and might be null
string greeting = day != null ? "hello there " + name : "";
```

It's fairly clear in the example I've provided, but when you are using getter/setters for view-models, it gets a bit confusing to stare at, and raises the chance of a logical error being missed. As such:

```
public DateTime? SearchDate {
    get { return _searchDate; }
    set { _searchDate = value != null ? value.Value : value; }
}
```

Comment: This is completely impossible.  However, you want C# 6's `?.`.

Comment: #EricLippert has already invented such an operator in his C#6.0 or whatever.

Comment: Also, that would be a _binary_ operator.

Comment: @AgentFire: Eric Lippert left the C# team before that operator was introduced.

Comment: Btw, the setter could simply be `_searchDate = value` and the other sample is confusing.

Comment: How is the example setter any different than `set { _searchDate = value; }`?

Comment: Also note that you can use `operator true` and `operator false` to allow instances of types to be used as a condition.

Comment: @SLaks Perhaps you could explain the difference between binary operator and unary operator then? I thought it depended on how many operands you must provide, e.g., x < y (here less-than is a binary operator) whereas !x (here exclamation is a unary operator).

Comment: @PatrickQ: Exactly.  Since you want to write `x !?? y`, that would be a binary operator.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I may have simplified the code too much for the sake of the question. The setter I am actually working with actually does a few operations on the data, IF there is actually data, otherwise it just leaves it as null. So it would be `searchDate = value.Value.Date.AddDays(1)`, for example.

Comment: @SLaks Nope, it's unary. In `x !?? y`, y is not an operand because the statement would expand to `if (x != null) then return y`. So y is simply the output. y fulfills the `then` clause of the conditional statement. I'm sure we are probably both saying the same thing, and ultimately I just failed to explain my question very well.

Comment: @PatrickQ: That is exactly what an operand means.

Comment: @SLaks I disagree. the value returned in the `then` portion of a conditional statement, has nothing to do with the operator in the condition. `if (condition) then {} else {}`. what you are saying would imply that `!x` would be unary operator if used as such `bool answer = !answer` and a binary operator if used as such `string msg = !answer ? "i dont know" : "i found it"` Your suggestion is inconsistent. By definition, an "operand" is "the quantity on which an operation is being done", which does not include results.

Comment: `if` is a statement, not an operator.  `?:` is a _ternary_ operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been said, you cannot declare new operators in C#, ever, at all. This is a limitation of the language, the compiler, and the environment.

What you CAN do is utilize the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) or write a few generic [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to handle what you want, such as

```
public static string EmptyIfNull(this string source, string ifValue, string ifNull = "")
{
    return source != null ? ifValue : ifNull;
}
```

and implemented via

```
string greeting = name.EmptyIfNull("hello there " + name);
```

Comment: Not only do I like this answer, but I understand the question better after having read it! :)

Comment: @aravol thanks. This is what I am doing already. I was just hoping to do something that read a little more clearly. Thanks for taking the time to answer me :)

Answer (score 6):

This is completely impossible.

Instead, you can use C# 6's `?.` operator:

```
value?.Value
```

Comment: You have it backwards sir, `?.`

Comment: @Haney: Oops; fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

C# does not let you define completely new operators, you can only overload a [specific set of existing operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to declare new operators in C# at all, all you can do is override the existing ones.